# Jhipster Gateway / Service usage

Tags: spring-cloud, jhipster

Within Jhipster the documentation states:

> **Generating entities in a microservices architecture**
>
> If you choose to generate the entity from a microservice, you will need to enter the path to this microservice on your local computer, and then JHipster will generate the front-end code on the gateway.

No lets say I have multiple Gateways.  Does this mean if I have a common Microservice Application.  I create the Microservice Application entity then run the generator within each Gateway that would use this service?

Is this the intent of the generator?

Comment: Yes. Using JDL studio, you can generate a single jhipster file with a microservice name on it and generate UI in multiple gateways. Please look https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/7018 for more information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can have multiple gateways which use the same microservice. As you said, you will have to run the generator within each Gateway and enter the path for your microservice.

The main intent was having one gateway communicating with multiple microservices.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.  In our case the application is to big to be handled via one UI.  I would end up trading a Spring MVC monolith for an Angular Monolith.